# angular2 PageNotFound always displayed instead of routes requested

Tags: angular, router

When I access

```
http://localhost:3000/main/home
```

then I get redirected to the PageNotFoundComponent instead of going to the 
main/home route.
When I take out the PageNotFoundComponent it works.
Here is my code:

My AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'notloggedin', component: NotLoggedInComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/main/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

My MainRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [ LoggedinUserGuard ],
    children: [
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'},
      { path: 'about', loadChildren: 'app/about/about.module#AboutModule'},
      { path: 'table', loadChildren: 'app/table/table.module#TableModule'},
      { path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user-list/user-list.module#UserListModule'},
    ]
  },
];
```

If someone could help it would be great
thanks

Comment: You are probably importing your modules in the wrong order. `MainRoutingModule` must be imprted before `AppRoutingModule`. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#routing-module-order

Comment: yes   thanks :) that was the source of the problem :)